# What is the difference between Use case and Use case model?

Tags: use-case

I'm delivering a project to a client and he is asking for 
Use case and use case model 
What is the difference between them ?

Comment: I've nominated for reopening - this question concerns understanding particular terms with clear definitions - does not seem "too broad".

Comment: @BartoszKP, I'm voting against re-opening. In its current form, it looks like the user did not trouble using a search engine and/or reading any of the abundant online documentation regarding the two compared terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [`Use case`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use_case) is a description of a single interaction between the user and the system. A [`Use case model`](http://www.sparxsystems.com/resources/tutorial/use_case_model.html) is a description of a whole functionality described with many use cases.

For example, if a system needs to manage some invoice related business process, then a use case model for such a process would consist of a use case describing steps required to add an invoice to the system, another use case describing what the user should do to sign it, and another use case presenting an invoice export scenario - etc..

Comment: My System Has 2 parts 
- Mobile App - Admin panel 
So the mobile user will have use case and admin will have one 
The use case model will gather all ??

Comment: Simply speaking, if we are talking about one functionality then yes, if there are really only single use cases for each user type.